# How to deny a node to be dropped at root level?

Tags: extjs

I have a Tree like this (ExtJS 6):

```
Root
 |____ Folder 1
 |        |____ Leaf A       
 |        |____ Leaf B       
 |____ Folder 2
```

Now I need to drag any `Leaf X` to any folder but can not drop it as `Root` child.
The rule is: A `Leaf` MUST be inside a `Folder`.

Here is my weak kung-fu:

My TreePanel controller:

```
Ext.define('MCLM.view.datawindow.ConfigDataPanelsTreeController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.configDataPanelsTreeController',

    viewready: function (tree) {

        var view = tree.getView();
        var dd = view.findPlugin('treeviewdragdrop');

        dd.dragZone.onBeforeDrag = function (data, e) {
            var rec = view.getRecord( e.getTarget( view.itemSelector ) );
            // Will not drag folders !
            return rec.isLeaf();
        };

        dd.dragZone.onDragOver = function(e, id) {
            var rec = view.getRecord( e.getTarget( view.itemSelector ) );
            // I know what I'm over but can't deny the drop
        };

    },
});
```

My TreePanel ( just important parts are kept ):

```
Ext.define('MCLM.view.datawindow.ConfigDataPanelsTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.TreePanel',
    xtype: 'view.configDataPanelsTree',
    id: 'configDataPanelsTree',

    requires: [
       'MCLM.view.datawindow.ConfigDataPanelsTreeController'
    ],     
    controller : 'configDataPanelsTreeController',


    viewConfig: {

        id:'configDataPanelsView',
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
        },
        listeners: {   
            beforedrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropHandlers) {

                dropHandlers.wait = true;
                // I know where I will drop, but when droping inside an EMPTY FOLDER, 
                // is like I'm droping at root level - There is no way to know I'm droping at 
                // root level.
                dropHandlers.processDrop();

            },

            drop: function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition) {
                // Already dropped .. what can I do?
            },
        } 
    },        

    listeners: {
         viewready: 'viewready',
    }

});
```

Comment: See: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/examples/classic/tree/custom-drop-logic.html

Comment: Good example, but this solution will deny the drop `INSIDE` the "not allowed" node but still allowing change a node from a folder to `ABOVE/BELOW` this folder. In my example, I will not be allowed to drop `Leaf A` OVER `Root` but still be possible to move `Leaf A` to BELOW `Folder 2` or ABOVE `Folder 1` and this will put the `Leaf A` at root level.

Comment: I'm not saying it does exactly what you want, but you can modify the logic to do that pretty trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Well... this is my first try and seems to be ok.

First add `tempParent : null` to the TreePanel, to store the parent of dragged node.

and then (TreePanel's body):

```
tempParent : null,

viewConfig: {
    markDirty:false,
    id:'configDataPanelsView',
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
    },
    listeners: {   

        beforedrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropHandlers) {
            dropHandlers.wait = true;

            console.log( "FROM : " + data.records[0].parentNode.data.text );
            // Store the node's current parent node
            var configDataPanelsTree = Ext.getCmp('configDataPanelsTree');
            configDataPanelsTree.tempParent = data.records[0].parentNode;

            dropHandlers.processDrop();

        },

        drop: function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition) {

            var me = data.records[0];
            // now will check if the current parent is the root. Can't allow this!
            var configDataPanelsTree = Ext.getCmp('configDataPanelsTree');
            var oldParent = configDataPanelsTree.tempParent;
            var currentParent = data.records[0].parentNode;

            console.log( "TO : " + currentParent.data.text );
            // If the new parent is root, then its parent is null !
            // Roll back the drag event by removing from current parent and inserting back in old parent.   
            if ( !currentParent.parentNode ) {
                me.remove();
                oldParent.appendChild( me );                
            }

        },

    } 
},
```

The problem is: when I roll back the node to its old parent, it falls at ent of the children list. Can I put it back to the old position?

**EDIT**

Solved: Ref: [node.insertChild()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-insertChild)

Added `tempIndex : 0` to the TreePanel's body.

Added to `beforedrop` event: 
`configDataPanelsTree.tempIndex = data.records[0].data.index;`

Added to `drop` event:
`var oldIndex = configDataPanelsTree.tempIndex;`

Chenged `drop` event:
from `oldParent.appendChild( me );` 
to `oldParent.insertChild( oldIndex, me);`

Now, after droped at root level the node comes back to its old position. My Kung-fu is not too bad after all ...

Comment: At the beginning of your `beforeDrop` handler, try adding `if (!node.parentNode) return false`.  I think that will animate the proxy return to the place from where it was dragged.

Comment: Not work. When I drop a leaf below a folder, the target will be that folder (even the drop was not IN the folder) so `node` will be the folder and its parent will be the root. My best bet still being this answer.